# What's the "DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS" (C compiler flag)?

Tags: c, compiler-flags

What's the "DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS" (C compiler flag)?

Comment: Actually `-DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` is the flag. See the comment on the Answer explaining the flag is `-D` is the flag, and `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` is its parameter. Ex in Xcode:  `-DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1`. Confusingly, this flag has no space between itself and its parameter. I am adding this comment to help get hits on this page with search engines.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS macro (no "D") suppresses the checks performed by NSAssert. You supply it to the compiler using `-DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` (see the comments for an explanation of the "D").

Comment: Just to clarify, `-D` defines a constant, and it is one of the confusing flags that doesn't have a space between it and it's parameter.