# Error : Define -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 in Project settings?

Tags: ios, xcode, svg

I am trying to build the svg file rendering demo. i am getting the following error that i am not able to understand.

[image: Error Image 1]

i have read the following answer [What's the "DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS" (C compiler flag)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752574/whats-the-dns-block-assertions-c-compiler-flag).

But after removing **D from the  -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1** its giving error like.

[image]

Comment: ka sunnida gujju lagas tu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the code. The lines:

```
#if !NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS
#error <error message>
#endif
```

This checks to see if the `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` macros has been defined or not. You are getting the error because `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` has not been set. The message after the `#error` is telling you how to fix the problem.

Once you define `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` in the "Other C Flags` build setting, the problems will go away.